# Keep runing into 'grub-install' fail. Whilst installing Mint

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot, grub

I have 2 SSDs, one with Windows 10 (sdd) and one that hopefully will have Linux Mint (sdc) on. I also have 2 HDDs that are in a raid array but this is exclusively for windows really and shouldn't really interfere.

I'm working with a bootable USB stick. I go into the OS then go to install Mint. Everything seems to run fine then nearer the end the bootloader issue arises.

`Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed. Fatal Error.`

The `sda` bit is what throws me. I've used linux a lot in the past but never understood the whole bootloader/grub scenario. I think the main issue is that in the past I've had Ubuntu on a HDD and set up EasyBCD to choose OS at boot rather than grub. I removed the Ubuntu drive and in it's place is an empty SSD as mentioned before. I uninstalled said EasyBCD but it's still showing the same boot up menu even after installation. Where should I be putting my bootloader? I want to dual boot Windows and Mint with them being on seperate drives.

There is also an option to install alongside Windows 10 but I *assume* that it'll put Mint on the same drive as the Windows one. So I normally go for 'erase everything' and then select the drive I want for Mint (sdc). Any thoughts or advice is welcome. I'm sure there've been a million questions like this but I couldn't find anyone that matched up with my problem.

Comment: BIOS or UEFI? MBR or GTP partition table(s)?

Comment: I used rufus to make the bootable usb. There I chose the option 'MBRfor BIOS and EUFI'. Thinking that would be the catch all option. I'm assuming you tink this is where the problem originates from? What option should I pick instead?

Comment: The computer, not the bootable stick. Is it using BIOS or UEFI boot? The hard disks are they GTP or MBR? In general whenever you have a out-of-the-ordinary setup (multiple hard disks etc.) you should chose "Something else" in the installer and specify partitions explicitly; this also allows you to specify explicitly where you want GRUB to be installed. If your computer allows you to chose `sdc` as a boot device, the put GRUB on `sdc`.

Comment: Apologies. My computer is UEFI as for the disks I've no idea now but I'll find out. Is this likely to have the caused the issue? As I mentioned it seems to install everything fine till the grub bit. Are you saying I should put the grub on the same drive I install mint onto? I'll be sure to do it, just want to be clear. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: GRUB must be installed (as in `grub-install`) on a disk which the computer allows you to select as a boot device. For a quick test, just perform a straightforward installation and install GRUB on the same disk as Mint, then try to boot from that disk.

Comment: Ok so Mint is installed (hurrah!). I put the boot loader on the same drive as Mint and it finished installation. As Windows is set as the default one it was only booting into that after a reboot. I went back to EasyBCD but couldn't add an entry for Mint drive. I had to boot into Mint (which I'm running now) by changing my boot drive priority. Also add your second comment as an answer if you want and I can mark this issue as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have a out-of-the-ordinary setup (multiple hard disks etc.) you should chose "Something else" in the installer and specify partitions explicitly; this also allows you to specify explicitly where you want GRUB to be installed. If your computer allows you to chose `sdc` as a boot device, then put GRUB on `sdc`, that, the disk on which you install Mint.